# Can I make glossaries issue a warning when I use an abbreviation before explaining it?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I want to use the `glossaries-extra` package to manage abbreviations. I prefer explicitly choosing where I use the long or the short form of the abbreviation (using the shortcuts `\al`, `as`, `af` etc.). It would be very helpful if there was a warning every time I use the short form of an abbreviation before explaining its meaning.

After skimming through the (very extensive) `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` documentations, I know that the package has the ability to keep track of how often an entry has been used and offers a lot of possibilities for configuration by the user. While I am fairly certain that the desired effect should be achievable without any hacks (i.e. only using user commands), it is unclear to me which part of the interface can be used to do it. How should I approach this?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
        abbreviations,
        nomain,
        shortcuts=abbreviations,
    ]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}
\newabbreviation{css}{CSS}{cascading style sheet}

\begin{document}

% this is fine
\af{html}, \as{html}

% this should produce a warning
\as{xml}

% as should this
\al{css}, \as{css}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you're interested in using `\ab{..}` instead. This will automatically print the long form (=`\al`) upon first use while all subsequent uses will only show the short form (=`\as`).

Comment: @leandriis: As I mentioned in my question, I prefer direct control over where I use the long or short form. I just need a warning when I edit the document in a way that an abbreviation is used before its explanation.